# Typescript method doesnt work well with event handler

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this simple TS script

```
class foo {
    v: number = 1;

    public bar() {
        console.log(this.v);
    }
}

var a = new foo();
var b = new foo();

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", a.bar);
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", b.bar);
```

and the HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <button id="test">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect to get 2 lines console output of number "1".

But NO! I get one `undefined` output

Lets take a look at the generated js file

```
var foo = (function () {
    function foo() {
    this.v = 1;
    }
    foo.prototype.bar = function () {
        console.log(this.v);
    };
    return foo;
}());
var a = new foo();
var b = new foo();
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", a.bar);
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", b.bar);
//# sourceMappingURL=Test.js.map
```

For performance consideration TS decided to put the function on the prototype! so the `addEventListener` call was actually adding the prototype (static) function twice and its the same instance. That's why I'm only getting one output instead of two.

And the biggest issue is that the `this` inside the prototype function refers to the button and button doesn't contain a property called `v`!

If we do this in native js

```
var foo = function () {
    this.v = 1;
    var that = this;
    this.bar = function () {
        console.log(that.v);
    }
}

var a = new foo();
var b = new foo();
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", a.bar);
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", b.bar);
```

we would get the desire result!

Is this a known issue for TS where you can't use the class method as event handler?

And how can I remove that handler after I added it?

Comment: `document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", a.bar);` => `document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", a.bar.bind(a));` (added `.bind(a)`). See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: *"For performance consideration TS decided to put the function on the prototype!"* No, it's on the prototype because that's where you said it should be, by using method syntax within a `class` construct. (It's also the right place to put it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't see why this is a duplicate. I clearly stated the fact I know why this is happening and I even posted an example of pure JS that's working. I just want to know how I can tell TS to generate the script so that it behaves the same way as the pure js I posted

Comment: SO's definition of a duplicate is that the answers there answer the question. The answers there do so: Use `bind`. Use a property you create in the constructor (or in a property initializer, since you're using TypeScript and you have those) as an arrow function. Use a wrapper function. Etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And how can I get two outputs? Since they both refer to the same function there will be only one listener added. And how can I remove only one of the listener but not both?

Comment: Exactly like you always do: Pass the same function into `removeEventListener`. Please do have a thorough read of the higher-rated answers to the linked question. If you use `bind`, that means remembering the bound function. If you use an arrow function created in the constructor (or property initializer), you can just use the function directly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are still missing my point. I added TWO event listeners to the click event. But I am only getting ONE console output. Where as my last example would produce TWO correct ones. .bind will only save me on the `this` part but not the handler part.

Comment: If you actually tried what the linked question's answers, and the comments above, describe, you'd find that you **do** get two console.logs: One per object. https://jsfiddle.net/avc4dqtw/

Comment: and https://jsfiddle.net/avc4dqtw/ (Yikes, the TypeScript feature of jsFiddle gets property initializers or arrow functions wrong, had to transpile this second one via the TS playground.)

Answer (score 0):

You can. Just do:

```
 document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", () => a.bar());
```

Comment: and how can I remove the listener..